# Angular js how to get index data into another template

Tags: javascript, templates

I'm trying to get data from a list into a single template in onsen, sort of the detail template
The controller has data already from an ajax http function, I get an empty page at the detail template though,
the shopitemcontroller is the controller I use to show the index data... the shop controller gets all the list data so a user can click and get the detail template
frustrating

```
module.controller('ShopItemController', function($scope){
    $scope.item = $scope.activeItem;
});
```

module.controller('ShopController', function($scope, $http, $interval){      $scope.items = $shop.items;

```
$scope.showItem = function(index){
    var activeItem = $scope.items[index];
    $scope.activeItem = activeItem;
    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('shop_item.html', {title : activeItem.item_title});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's very hard to read what you wrote because you're not using any commas and dots.

Make an `angular service` which you'll use as parameter for both `controllers`.

Example:

```
app.factory('generalService', function ($timeout, $http, $q, $resource, a) {

var service = {
   activeItem :null
};


return service;
});




module.controller('ShopController', function($scope, $http, $interval,generalService){ 
    $scope.items = $shop.items;
    $scope.showItem = function(index){
      var activeItem = $scope.items[index];
      generalService.activeItem = activeItem;
      $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('shop_item.html', {title : activeItem.item_title});
    };
});
```

So, you'll have something like this:

```
module.controller('ShopItemController', function($scope, generalService){

function refresh(){
  $scope.item = generalService.activeItem;
}
$scope.$watch(function(){return generalService.activeItem}, function(){return refresh();});
});
```

Comment: thanks!, I figured out how to correct my error though, its a long code shall I publish?

Comment: dunno, you choice.. If you think it will help anyone post it